# Multiple INSERTS in one query Joomla

Tags: joomla-2.5, mysql, sql

How can I do multiple inserts like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`fied1`, `field2`, `field3`) VALUES ('one', 'two', 'three'),('four', 'five', 'six');
INSERT INTO `table` (`fied1`, `field2`, `field3`) VALUES ('seven', 'eight', 'nine'),('ten', 'eleven', 'twelve');"
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

I can't split this query because I'm getting it from large text file.

Comment: I just want to make clear for the benefit of researchers, that this technique implements no security precautions.  This is blindly inserting data into the database.  There isn't even any escaping going on.  This _might_ be okay if your data source is 100% trusted/static/internal/prepared, but my general advice is not to go down the path of multi-inserting.  `mysqli`'s `multi_query()` is not to be trusted as prepared statement cannot be implemented with it.  For anyone playing with csv's, `LOAD DATA INFILE` will get Google to show you a good technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JDatabaseDriver::splitSql($query)` so your function will look like this:

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`fied1`, `field2`, `field3`) VALUES ('one', 'two', 'three'),('four', 'five', 'six');
    INSERT INTO `table` (`fied1`, `field2`, `field3`) VALUES ('seven', 'eight', 'nine'),('ten', 'eleven', 'twelve');";
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $queries = $db->splitSql($query);
    foreach( $queries AS $sql ) {
        $db->setQuery($sql);
        $db->execute();
    }
```

Comment: [This method](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseDriver.html#method_splitSql) is tagged as `deprecated`. Is there a replacement or has this been abandoned?  Can you point me to a url that shows the source code for this method?

Comment: You can find it in here https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/database/database.php#L126 and as far as I can see it is depreced only when you use it stright from JDatabase. So if you use it on `JDatabaseDriver` (that is the object returned from `JFactory::getDbo()`) you can still use it. They just inform about from where the method comes from.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the sql and run the statements using below code

```
    function insertSql($filename){
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $status = true;

        //parsing of SQL file 
        $sql_file_path = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/xxx/sql/install/mysql/'.$filename.'.sql';
        $queries = JDatabaseDriver::splitSql(file_get_contents($sql_file_path));
        foreach ($queries as $query)
        {
            $query = trim($query);
            if ($query != '' && $query{0} != '#')
            {
                $db->setQuery($query);
                if (!$db->execute())
                {
                    $application->enqueueMessage(JText::sprintf('JLIB_INSTALLER_ERROR_SQL_ERROR', $db->stderr(true)), 'error');
                    $status  = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return $status;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
$db = $this->getDBO();  
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`field1`,`field2`,`field3`)  
VALUES   
('one', 'two', 'three'),  
('four', 'five', 'six'),  
('seven', 'eight', 'nine'),
('ten', 'eleven', 'twelve')
";  
$db->setQuery($query);  
$db->query();
```

Comment: Nope. I need to comply with the max_allowed_packet limit = 16Mb

Comment: In mysql you can set max_allowed_packet limit = 16Mb refer this (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html).. i can't understand what you want.

Comment: I cant change this var, because site is on shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a workaround:

```
$sqlstr = "INSERT INTO `table` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`) VALUES ('1', 'x', 'p');";
$sqlstr .= "INSERT INTO `table` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`) VALUES ('1', 'x', 'p');";

[etc.]

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$m = $db->getConnection();
$m->multi_query($sqlstr);
```